# GWT SuggestBox with placeholder attribute

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm looking for a way to specify the placeholder attribute inside a `<g:SuggestBox>` element, in GWT.
I know that the `<input>` element allows to specify that attribute, but I decided to switch to the SuggestBox element instead of the input one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can define any additional properties adapting [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450987/how-to-add-a-placeholder-to-a-gwt-text-input-field/38316205#38316205).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create your own custom SuggestBox widget, after that you can set placeholder attribute to it. For example:

```
public class CustomSuggestBox extends SuggestBox {


 private String placeHolderText = "";

  public String getPlaceHolderText() {
   return placeHolderText;
  }

  public void setPlaceHolderText(String text) {
    placeHolderText = text;
    getTextBox().getElement().setAttribute("placeHolder", placeHolderText);
  }
}
```

So, you can set this property in UI binder.

```
<widgets:CustomSuggestBox ui:field="cSuggestBox"  placeHolderText="someText" />
```

PS: It works only in modern browser. For implementing it correctly for older browsers as well check out third-party lib [wogwt](http://code.google.com/p/wogwt/), it has [TextBoxWithPlaceholder](http://code.google.com/p/wogwt/source/browse/trunk/WOGWT/Sources/wogwt/translatable/TextBoxWithPlaceholder.java?spec=svn90&r=90)  class which extends TextBox:

```
 /**
 * A text box that displays a placeholder string when empty
 * 
 * <h3>CSS Style Rules</h3>
 * <ul class='css'>
 * <li>.wogwt-TextBoxWithPlaceholder { primary style }</li>
 * <li>.wogwt-TextBoxWithPlaceholder-placeholder { dependent style set when 
 * the placeholder is displayed }</li>
 * </ul>
 */
```

In that case you can send this `TextBoxWithPlaceholder`'s instance to `SuggestBox(SuggestOracle oracle, TextBoxBase box)` constructor.

Comment: I am not sure that this code getTextBox().getElement().getStyle().setProperty("placeholder", placeHolderText); is correct.  I think it should be as described below.

Answer (score 9):

Subclassing a `SuggestBox` would definately work.
If you don't want to create an additional class you can also easily add the placeHolder to an existing `SuggestBox`by setting the attribute directly:

```
SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox();
suggestBox.getElement().setAttribute("placeHolder", "SOME TEXT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you will get an exception if you call the `getElement()` method before the widget is added to the DOM.  So if you want a solution that allows you to set the placeholder text before it's added to the DOM, and have it appear once it's added, you can hook in to the `AttachEvent`:

```
SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox();
// com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.Handler
suggestBox.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
        if (event.isAttached()) {
            suggestBox.getElement().setAttribute("placeHolder", "SOME TEXT);
        }
    }
});
```